# Very Complex Json with same field name

Tags: flutter, dart

My colleague is response for backend development, this is one of example of the API response.
I want to know that how can I separate it to the map?
And There have same name, I am very difficult to handle it. JSON to Dart generated code also will have error case by same name.
Is there have any other solution to handle this Json?

```
{
    "formId": 1,
    "formTypeId": 2,
    "formTemplateId": 1,
    "version": 1,
    "history": "N",
    "refNum": "AGQ/T01/01/A1/QA2/0001",
    "dateOfAcceptance": "2020/12/16 14:54:01",
    "dateOfReacceptance": "2020/12/16 14:54:01",
    "blockId": 242,
    "floorId": 1,
    "flatId": 98,
    "isPublic": "N",
    "locationId": 1,
    "fromFloorId": 1,
    "toFloorId": 2,
    "elevationId": 1,
    "isNextVendor": "Y",
    "isMultipleVendor": "N",
    "formStatusId": 1,
    "checkResults": 1,
    "submissionDate": "2020/12/16 14:54:01",
    "submittedBy": "ADMINISTRATOR",
    "siteId": "YLTL",
    "formDetails": [
        {
            "formDetailsId": 1,
            "formId": 1,
            "title": "A. 驗收項目",
            "checkType": 1,
            "required": "Y",
            "parentId": 0,
            "orderNum": 1,
            "formDetailsOptions": [],
            "fromDetails": [
                {
                    "formDetailsId": 3,
                    "formId": 1,
                    "title": "Title group",
                    "checkType": 2,
                    "required": "Y",
                    "parentId": 1,
                    "orderNum": 1,
                    "formDetailsOptions": [],
                    "fromDetails": [
                        {
                            "formDetailsId": 4,
                            "formId": 1,
                            "title": "門編號：",
                            "checkType": 5,
                            "required": "Y",
                            "parentId": 3,
                            "orderNum": 1,
                            "answerVal": "A001",
                            "formDetailsOptions": []
                        },
                        {
                            "formDetailsId": 5,
                            "formId": 1,
                            "title": "位置：",
                            "checkType": 6,
                            "required": "Y",
                            "parentId": 3,
                            "orderNum": 2,
                            "formDetailsOptions": [
                                {
                                    "formDetailsOptionsId": 1,
                                    "formDetailsId": 5,
                                    "orderNum": 1,
                                    "optionDesc": "單位大門",
                                    "defectOpts": "N",
                                    "additionOpts": "N",
                                    "selected": "N"
                                },
                                {
                                    "formDetailsOptionsId": 2,
                                    "formDetailsId": 5,
                                    "orderNum": 2,
                                    "optionDesc": "廚房門",
                                    "defectOpts": "N",
                                    "additionOpts": "N",
                                    "selected": "N"
                                },
                                {
                                    "formDetailsOptionsId": 3,
                                    "formDetailsId": 5,
                                    "orderNum": 3,
                                    "optionDesc": "廁所客廳",
                                    "defectOpts": "N",
                                    "additionOpts": "N",
                                    "selected": "N"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "formDetailsId": 6,
                            "formId": 1,
                            "title": "假框抆塞：",
                            "checkType": 4,
                            "required": "Y",
                            "parentId": 3,
                            "orderNum": 3,
                            "answerVal": "Y",
                            "formDetailsOptions": []
                        },
                        {
                            "formDetailsId": 7,
                            "formId": 1,
                            "title": "門框尺寸：",
                            "checkType": 4,
                            "required": "Y",
                            "parentId": 3,
                            "orderNum": 4,
                            "answerVal": "Y",
                            "formDetailsOptions": []
                        },
                        {
                            "formDetailsId": 8,
                            "formId": 1,
                            "title": "門框木料：",
                            "checkType": 4,
                            "required": "Y",
                            "parentId": 3,
                            "orderNum": 5,
                            "answerVal": "Y",
                            "formDetailsOptions": []
                        },
                        {
                            "formDetailsId": 9,
                            "formId": 1,
                            "title": "門框接口：",
                            "checkType": 4,
                            "required": "Y",
                            "parentId": 3,
                            "orderNum": 6,
                            "answerVal": "Y",
                            "formDetailsOptions": []
                        },
                        {
                            "formDetailsId": 10,
                            "formId": 1,
                            "title": "門框色澤：",
                            "checkType": 4,
                            "required": "Y",
                            "parentId": 3,
                            "orderNum": 7,
                            "answerVal": "Y",
                            "formDetailsOptions": []
                        },
                        {
                            "formDetailsId": 11,
                            "formId": 1,
                            "title": "磨耳及蟻油：",
                            "checkType": 4,
                            "required": "Y",
                            "parentId": 3,
                            "orderNum": 8,
                            "answerVal": "Y",
                            "formDetailsOptions": []
                        },
                        {
                            "formDetailsId": 12,
                            "formId": 1,
                            "title": "防火膠條：",
                            "checkType": 4,
                            "required": "Y",
                            "parentId": 3,
                            "orderNum": 9,
                            "answerVal": "Y",
                            "formDetailsOptions": []
                        },
                        {
                            "formDetailsId": 13,
                            "formId": 1,
                            "title": "平正及穩固：",
                            "checkType": 4,
                            "required": "Y",
                            "parentId": 3,
                            "orderNum": 10,
                            "answerVal": "Y",
                            "formDetailsOptions": []
                        },
                        {
                            "formDetailsId": 14,
                            "formId": 1,
                            "title": "備註：",
                            "checkType": 7,
                            "required": "N",
                            "parentId": 3,
                            "orderNum": 11,
                            "answerVal": "Test group remark",
                            "formDetailsOptions": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "formDetailsId": 2,
            "formId": 1,
            "title": "B. 要改善位置及詳情備註：",
            "checkType": 1,
            "required": "Y",
            "parentId": 0,
            "orderNum": 2,
            "answerVal": "Test B remark",
            "formDetailsOptions": []
        }
    ],
    "formDefects": [
        {
            "formDefectsId": 1,
            "formId": 1,
            "defectRemark": "Test Remark",
            "followActionId": 1,
            "reporterType": 1,
            "formDefectsImgs": [
                {
                    "formDefectsImgId": 1,
                    "formDefectsId": 1,
                    "imgType": 1,
                    "filePath": "data/images/1/DEFECT-20201228150623123-2F3F4H.jpg",
                    "orderNum": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "formVendors": [
        {
            "formVendorId": 2,
            "formId": 1,
            "vendorId": "3954",
            "orderNum": 2,
            "isNextVendor": "N",
            "formVendorImgs": [
                {
                    "formVendorImgId": 1,
                    "formVendorId": 2,
                    "filePath": "data/images/1/QUERY-20201228151423123-2FF2V4.png",
                    "orderNum": 1
                }
            ],
            "vendor": {
                "vendorId": "3954",
                "vendorDesc": "博西華",
                "vendorDescDisp": "BSH"
            }
        }
    ],
    "formNextVendors": [
        {
            "formVendorId": 1,
            "formId": 1,
            "vendorId": "3985",
            "orderNum": 1,
            "isNextVendor": "Y",
            "formVendorImgs": [
                {
                    "formVendorImgId": 2,
                    "formVendorId": 1,
                    "filePath": "data/images/1/QUERY-20201228151423123-VD5F5H.png",
                    "orderNum": 2
                }
            ],
            "vendor": {
                "vendorId": "3985",
                "vendorDesc": "瑞基",
                "vendorDescDisp": "Zuki"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: *"And There have same name,"* - which one?

Comment: formId,fromDetails,formDetailsId

Comment: but they are in different maps - it should not be any problem with that

Answer (score 0):

With this kind of complex json i would suggest using dart packages for serialization.  For example:

https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable

or

https://pub.dev/packages/built_value

Answer (score 0):

If you can share Dart models, then use json_serializable package. That would make things easier. But...

...if you have to live with the JSON response that your colleague developed and you cannot share your models that convert from/to Json, one alternative would be to use https://app.quicktype.io/

I entered your JSON response and out came generated Dart code that seems legit, at a first glance at least.

Example from that code generation:

```
factory ComplexJson.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ComplexJson(
    formId: json["formId"],
    formTypeId: json["formTypeId"],
    formTemplateId: json["formTemplateId"],
    version: json["version"],
    history: historyValues.map[json["history"]],
    refNum: json["refNum"],
    dateOfAcceptance: json["dateOfAcceptance"],
    dateOfReacceptance: json["dateOfReacceptance"],
    blockId: json["blockId"],
    floorId: json["floorId"],
    flatId: json["flatId"],
    isPublic: historyValues.map[json["isPublic"]],
    locationId: json["locationId"],
    fromFloorId: json["fromFloorId"],
    toFloorId: json["toFloorId"],
    elevationId: json["elevationId"],
    isNextVendor: historyValues.map[json["isNextVendor"]],
    isMultipleVendor: historyValues.map[json["isMultipleVendor"]],
    formStatusId: json["formStatusId"],
    checkResults: json["checkResults"],
    submissionDate: json["submissionDate"],
    submittedBy: json["submittedBy"],
    siteId: json["siteId"],
    formDetails: List<MDetail>.from(json["formDetails"].map((x) => MDetail.fromJson(x))),
    formDefects: List<FormDefect>.from(json["formDefects"].map((x) => FormDefect.fromJson(x))),
    formVendors: List<FormVendor>.from(json["formVendors"].map((x) => FormVendor.fromJson(x))),
    formNextVendors: List<FormVendor>.from(json["formNextVendors"].map((x) => FormVendor.fromJson(x))),
);
```